# why pin-project implement Unpin for any struct when no structural fields?

Tags: rust

```
use std::marker::PhantomPinned;

use pin_project::pin_project;

#[pin_project]
struct Struct<T> {
    field: T,
    #[pin] // <------ This `#[pin]` is required to make `Struct` to `!Unpin`.
    _pin: PhantomPinned,
}
```

Note that using `PhantomPinned` without `#[pin]` attribute has no effect.

Rust auto-implements `Unpin` when all struct fields implement `Unpin`, but with `#[pin_project]`'s macro, if no `#[pin]` field, the struct always implements `Unpin`, event if it has `!Unpin` fields.

Why is `pin-project` designed this way?

Comment: Heads up: your question is worded badly, "Why is it designed this way" has a strong opinion-based sound to it and your question will probably be closed based on that alone.  "What's the purpose of it" is probably a better question. I know it's subtle, but I've seen it repeatedly.

Comment: @Finomnis I disagree. Surely this was the OP's intent, so I think closing it is just being pedantic for no reason.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I agree, I just said it because it already has one close vote, which I disagree with. I'd personally also be interested in why pin_project behaves this way.

Answer (score 1):

What does `!Unpin` means? It means "if this is pinned, it cannot be unpinned anymore". Or, "pinning is meaningful for this type".

By default, all fields are [*structurally pinned*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/#projections-and-structural-pinning). What this means is that if you have `Pin<&mut Struct>`, you can safely (conceptually; it may require unsafe code, but it is within the guarantees of `Pin`) create a `Pin<&mut Field>` from it. In other words, if the struct is pinned, the field is also pinned. Therefore, if the field is `!Unpin`, the struct is also `!Unpin` - otherwise, we could take a `Pin<&mut Struct>`, project it to `Pin<&mut Field>`, then unpin it and overwrite the `!Unpin` field while it is pinned.

With `pin-project`, only fields that are marked `#[pin]` are structurally pinned. Other fields are **not** structurally pinned. Therefore, if we have a `Pin<&mut Struct>`, we cannot create a `Pin<&mut NonPinField>` if we cannot guarantee that the field is never going to be unpinned - this is not within the guarantees of the existing `Pin<&mut Struct>`.

Therefore, the fact that we have a `Pin<&mut Struct>` doesn't mean that we pinned the field. And if we never pin any `!Unpin` field, that means we can be pinned and unpinned easily - pinning is not meaningful for our type, because it doesn't allow you to pin a `!Unpin` type. Thus, we can be `Unpin`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`#[pin_project]`](https://docs.rs/pin-project/latest/pin_project/attr.pin_project.html) attribute is designed for structs and enums where at least one of the fields is [`!Unpin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Unpin.html) and provides a safe interface for accessing both `Unpin` and `!Unpin` fields. By default, no fields are considered structurally pinned by `#[pin_project]`. If you do not add a `#[pin]` then the macro will generate access to `&mut Field` from `Pin<&mut Struct>`.

So even if a field is `!Unpin`, by omitting `#[pin]`, you are creating a way to access an unprotected `&mut Field`. Therefore, you are not treating it as pinned by `Pin<&mut Struct>` and thus your struct can still be `Unpin`.

> Why `pin-project` implement `Unpin` for any struct when no structural fields?

Directly from the Rust [`std::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/pin/#pinning-is-structural-for-field) module (emphasis mine): *"The struct must only be `Unpin` if all the **structural** fields are `Unpin`.*" And by omitting `#[pin]`, you are communicating to the macro that the field is not structural (unlike how the compiler considers all fields structural when auto-implementing `Unpin`).

> Why is `pin-project` designed this way?

For one, a macro does not know the properties of the fields it sees, it only sees the AST for the struct or enum that it is attached to. So it cannot know that `_pin` is `!Unpin` or not and act accordingly.

With that in mind, it makes more sense for the structural pinning behavior to be opt-in rather than opt-out. Almost all Rust types are `Unpin`, and if you were to try to use a `&mut Field` that is `!Unpin` as a `Pin<&mut Field>` (as is common when implementing `Future` or third-party `Async*` trait) then you would have to use `unsafe` to do so and negates the benefits of using the macro.